# Javascript error prevents loading later javascript files

Tags: javascript

Why this odd behavior?

An error in javascript inside a script tag prevented the javascript included with a 2nd script tag from working. Commenting the bad lines allowed the 2nd, included script to work.

My question is, why does it behave this way? Shouldn't a second, included script be unaffected by any kind of errors in a separate, unrelated script element?

It took me awhile to fix this, because although I saw errors in the console, they weren't in my included script and therefore seemed irrelevant.

Here is the console error:

```
jquery.table.addrow.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
    at ExpandableTable.live (jquery.table.addrow.js:26)
    at init.$.fn.btnAddRow.$.fn.tableAutoAddRow (jquery.table.addrow.js:299)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (?c=cf&v=sis&sf=cs&n=63:28)
    at fire (jquery.js:3048)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3160)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:433)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:104)
```

And here is the code that caused the error. After I comment the offending code in the first `<script>` element, the 2nd `<script>` element works perfectly:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="/includes/js/jquery-ui/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/includes/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/includes/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='/includes/js/jquery.jeditable.mini.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/includes/js/jquery.table.addrow.js'></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() { 
    // THESE ARE THE BAD LINES
         $('.appendRow').btnAddRow({rowNumColumn:'rowNumber'});
        $('.delRow').btnDelRow();
       });
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="asdf.js"></script>
```

Nothing inside of asdf.js works unless I comment the 2 "bad lines" in the first script. E.g.

asdf.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert('hahaha'); // no output. document is never ready?
});
```

Now if I comment the "bad lines" in script one like so:

```
//$('.appendRow').btnAddRow({rowNumColumn:'rowNumber'});
//$('.delRow').btnDelRow();
```

Then script 2 works! So I don't think the issue can be with jQuery not being loaded. Otherwise, script 2 still wouldn't work after commenting the "bad lines" in script 1.

Comment: Open your browser console, do you see an error report? If so include that into your question. If you are moving the order of the JS files around it could be the reason for the error as something might not be defined...

Comment: without seeing your code, can only guess that what you think is unimportant actually is important

Comment: @JaromandaX well now you can see it!

Comment: @NewToJS I included the error. But all I had to do was comment the "bad lines" in the first script for the 2nd script to work.

Comment: When are you adding JQuery?

Comment: @SDhaliwal way before all of this. The jquery in script 2 works as soon as I comment the bad lines in script 1. Is it normal for errors in 1 script to prevent a 2nd script from working? Is it like a fatal error that prevents any further javascript processing?

Comment: It could be due to the fact it is firing as the page is loading, and the DOM is not ready

Comment: @SDhaliwal actually I do have document ready function around the body of the first script. I just edited the question to show that.

Comment: @SDhaliwal exactly what I were trying to say :p order of the JS files and the script running before the DOM is ready leaving thing undefined. **Buttle Butkus** have you included the jQuery library before trying to execute your JS file? If you want to use the `jQuery` libaray it must be listed/added before your external js file or before your script tag otherwise you will find a `$` or `$()` syntax error in the console.

Comment: @NewToJS yes but actually it can't be that because the 1st script also has document ready function. I just forgot to show it. Question edited.

Comment: What does "not working" mean in the case of the second script? Does the second script run with errors, or not run at all, or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn anything I put into it doesn't fire. I even tried deleting everything except just `alert('hahaha')` inside of document ready. Nothing triggered. It was as if the script wasn't there.

Comment: @ButtleButkus that sounds like you haven't included the jQuery libaray or it is failing to load the jQuery library. Would you mind doing a quick copy/paste of what you have on the page you're trying to run please https://pastebin.com/ thank you. .

Comment: @NewToJS the whole browser html? Not sure I can do that. But please see my edit near the bottom. I'm sure jquery is loaded. I can run jquery functions from the console. And script 2 works if I just comment out 2 "bad lines" in script 1. Unless those bad lines somehow *unload* jquery, it must still be loaded.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Well share the order of all `<script>` tags you have in the document.

Comment: @NewToJS Ok I added them all to the question. It's just jquery, jquery-ui, and some jquery modules, and then my custom scripts at the end.

Comment: why are you guys voting to close? Explain how this is not a legitimate coding question.